# How to crop bottom part of an image(part with subtitle) in python

Tags: python, image, opencv, ocr

I am doing subtitle extraction from videos in python.I have used opencv in python to do this.I have divided it into frames and for each frame as image which will be stored in my disk, i am doing ocr on it.But I dont want to perform ocr on the entire image.I just want the subtitle part.I manually cropped the image with these values 278:360 as my image size was 360:640.But the image size varies for different video files.Now my question is how to crop the subtitle part alone programatically.Please do answer.Thanks in advance

```
    textImage = image[278:360,:]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the last third of the image height, if you are sure that the subtitles will be there.

For instance, for the following image:

[image]

Proceed as follows:

1. read the image into a numpy array :

In my example, I am using `imread` from `skimage.io`, but you can use `opencv`:

```
from skimage.io import imread 
img = imread('http://cdn.wccftech.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/subtitle-of-a-blu-ray-movie.jpg')
img.shape #   >>> (383, 703, 3)
```

2. Get the bottom third of the image (which contains the subtitle):

The idea is to divide the height of the image by 3 and take the bottom third of the image:

```
crop_position = int(img.shape[0]/3)
subtitle_img = img[img.[0] - crop_position:,:,:]
```

The resulting `subtitle_img` looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much it worked.And sorry cant upvote because i have less reputation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use only one library and regular operations on arrays:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image= mpimg.imread('someImage.jpg')

#Example for bottom half of an image, but you can replace this with your parameter
crop_position = image.shape[0] // 2

half_imagage = image[image.shape[0] - crop_position:,:]
```

And it returns a nice image:
[image]